# Should I Use a RecyclerView to Show a Collection List?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm currently building an iOS and Android project for a company and I have a question about the user interface for the Android side. Should I use a RecyclerView on my Android app to accomplish what I have in the Our Section on my iOS app? Or what element should I be using? Thank you!

// Android

[image]

// iOS

[image]

Comment: if you mean ' Our stories' section I think RecyclerView can help. It's will be challenging to create a Card View  for  RecyclerView but it's doable and at the end you can Intent to navigate to the fullscreen.  Obviously I'm not very skilled at android yet so I suggest not to take my advice instantly.

Comment: If it's always three views that fit without scrolling, then RecyclerView isn't the best fit. In that case I'd use a ConstraintLayout and manually place three of the same child view layout.

Comment: It will have more than three views, it will be scrollable

Comment: If it's a dynamic list then use a recycler view. There are not really other alternatives that haven't been deprecated.